# The following build commands failed: SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\

Tags: ios, react-native, x86-64

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ projectName (in target 'projectName' from project 'projectName')
SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ projectName (in target 'projectName' from project 'projectName')
(2 failures)

This issue i'm getting when i run "yarn ios" / "npx react-native run-ios" command.Using XCode its working fine.